# Reading, parsing and sorting data from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I need to read in a csv file, parse it and then sort the value according to these parameter:

1. The top 10 selling products
2. The top performing branches
3. The worst performing branches
4. The employee who took the most sales

Here is my code so far, any advice on how to sort it?

```
import java.io.*;

public class CSV {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/K:/ConnexicaWork/data/data.csv"))) {
        String[] dataArray = null;
        String data = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read first line.

        while (data != null) {
            data = data.replace(",00", ".00");
            dataArray = data.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"); //split on the comma only if that comma has zero, or an even number of quotes in ahead of it.
            for (String item : dataArray) {
                System.out.print(dataArray[34] + " # ");
            }
            System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
            data = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }
    }


    System.out.println();  // End the printout with a blank line.

}
}
```

Comment: Eugh. Use a [csv parsing library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to avoid issues with escape chars. Use bean binding to bind you data to a JavaBean. Store these in a `List` then use `Collections.sort` and `Lists.subList`. Magic...

Comment: I don't recommend you use regex. Maybe antlr?

Comment: @tbodt don't you think antlr is a little to heavy for parsing a csv?

Comment: Ok, now @BoristheSpider has a CVS parsing library that you *really should use*.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how would I store these in lists? sorry newish to java

Comment: Then start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).